# golang upload via FTP and get FTP progress in a same time

Tags: go, concurrency, ftp

I've used http://github.com/dutchcoders/goftp to send a file via FTP. It works normally but when I want to upload a file and get that file info (at the same time) It doesn't work!

```
fileName := "sth"
var err error
var ftp *goftp.FTP

if ftp, err = goftp.Connect("serverip:port"); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

defer ftp.Close()

config := tls.Config{
    InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    ClientAuth:         tls.RequestClientCert,
}

if err = ftp.AuthTLS(config); err != nil {
    //      log.Println("1", err)
}

if err = ftp.Login("userName", "pass"); err != nil {
    log.Println("2", err)
}
//
if err = ftp.Cwd("/home/myDir/"); err != nil {
    log.Println("3", err)
}

var file *os.File
if file, err = os.Open(fileName); err != nil {
    log.Println("6", err)
}
defer file.Close()

fmt.Println("start")

go func() {
    fmt.Println("first")
    nmp := ftp.Stor(fileName, file)
    if nmp != nil {
        log.Println("7", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("first is runung")

    }
}()

go func() {
    fmt.Println("second")
    for {
        files, nms := ftp.List(fileName)
        if nms == nil {
            fmt.Println(files)
        }
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
}()

fmt.Println("end")

var mnmn string
fmt.Scan(&mnmn)
```

ftp.Stor func won't run and my code returns below outputs:

> ```
> start
> end
> first
> second
> 2016/05/31 13:21:38 7 <nil>
> []
> []
> ```

Comment: Can you share the complete main? Are you blocking the main? Otherwise, it won't wait for go routine.

Comment: @khrm I've edited my question please check it!

Comment: You can keep take two different instance of ftp. Then it works properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, both the goroutine have same ftp instance (var ftp *goftp.FTP
) which are blocking each other as they have race condition. And your result is unpredictable. Sometime, it gives correct result when first execute properly. Or when it waits for second and then runs completely. Or when first doesn't execute. Otherwise, both the go routine are blocking each other. 
Solutons:

- You take two different instances of ftp to give different connections to goroutine

  ```
  var ftp,ftp1 *goftp.FTP
  ```

Like here [Play Golang](https://play.golang.org/p/wpZf3PLVR5)
Or

- Have *goftp stor first in main go routine. Then start other go routine. But it will defeat the purpose of second go routine.

Comment: Yeu mean It's happend because of FTP technology? If yes what's the best way to have access to the file info here (upload time) SSH?

Comment: @MasoodAfrashteh I made myself more clear. It's not due to ftp technology but  *goftp.FTP. You are using same connection in both go routine.

Comment: @MasoodAfrashteh  I added the code explaining that. I am running ftp server in local machine, so I made appropriate changes.

Comment: Thanks but isn't better for me to use SSH in this situation I think we can implement something like rsync with that. I just trying to find an efficient way...

Comment: Yes. Rsync is better.

Comment: But I am not sure how to proceed with that in golang.